# How to do a project-wide sweep for "Remove redundant catch" using Resharper?

Tags: resharper

I am dealing with a large old codebase that has a lot of these:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

Resharper helpfully marks these and offers the option to "Remove redundant catch", but I don't like having to go through one-by-one, I would like to wipe them out all at once.  Is there a way to do that with Resharper, possibly by integrating it in with "Code cleanup"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Resharper 5.0 you can import the following pattern (save it as an xml file) into the Pattern Catalog (Resharper>Tools>Pattern Catalog>Import) then run Search Now to find all instances so that you can review and choose to perform the replacement on them.

```
<CustomPatterns>
  <Pattern Severity="HINT">
    <Comment>useless catch</Comment>
    <ReplaceComment>remove useless catch</ReplaceComment>
    <ReplacePattern>$code$</ReplacePattern>
    <SearchPattern><![CDATA[try
{
    $code$
}
catch
{
    throw;
}]]></SearchPattern>
    <Params />
    <Placeholders>
      <StatementPlaceholder Name="code" Minimal="1" Maximal="-1" />
    </Placeholders>
  </Pattern>
</CustomPatterns>
```

The pattern worked on my test code. I don't know how the Pattern matching engine handles whitespace so you may have to change tabs to spaces or whatever your code standard is as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Handcraftsman!  Just to check, I emailed JetBrains and they told me the same thing:  "there's no way to apply a certain quick-fix (such as 'Remove redundant catch') solution-wide, but you can use the new Structural Search and Replace functionality to search and replace such constructs."

A little walk-through is on their blog:
http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/04/introducing-resharper-50-structural-search-and-replace/